# Is there a way to "flip" an AnimationClip horizontally?

Tags: three.js

I have a series of animations that are applied to the right arm of a character, and one of them needs to be done exactly the same but with the left arm.

In Unity there is the "mirror" option, which does exactly what I want:

[Mirror in Unity](https://youtu.be/KHCNxUR9EmY)

But, in addition to the fact that I have not found a way to export the animation with the mirror applied, I am more interested in achieving that effect programatically.

I have tried to scale the object (multiply the x coordinate by -1), but since the rest of the animations must continue as they are, if I apply the scaling only when the animation is played, the result is not good, since I cannot make a smooth transition between animations. So I think the only code-level solution is to manipulate the AnimationClip object that contains the animation.

From what I've seen, the object contains a list of tracks, each consisting of a list of times and a list of values. But all my attempts to modify those values ​​produce a strange result that does not allow me to draw any conclusions about how it works:

```
0: VectorKeyframeTrack
createInterpolant: ƒ InterpolantFactoryMethodLinear( result )
name: "BD_Spine_01_jnt.position"
times: Float32Array(46) [0, 0.01666666753590107, 0.03333333507180214, 0.05000000074505806, 0.06666667014360428, 0.0833333358168602, 0.10000000149011612, 0.11666666716337204, 0.13333334028720856, 0.15000000596046448, 0.1666666716337204, 0.18333333730697632, 0.20000000298023224, 0.21666666865348816, 0.23333333432674408, 0.25, 0.2666666805744171, 0.28333333134651184, 0.30000001192092896, 0.3166666626930237, 0.3333333432674408, 0.3499999940395355, 0.36666667461395264, 0.38333332538604736, 0.4000000059604645, 0.4166666567325592, 0.4333333373069763, 0.44999998807907104, 0.46666666865348816, 0.4833333194255829, 0.5, 0.5166666507720947, 0.5333333611488342, 0.550000011920929, 0.5666666626930237, 0.5833333134651184, 0.6000000238418579, 0.6166666746139526, 0.6333333253860474, 0.6499999761581421, 0.6666666865348816, 0.6833333373069763, 0.699999988079071, 0.7166666388511658, 0.7333333492279053, 0.75, buffer: ArrayBuffer(184), byteLength: 184, byteOffset: 0, length: 46, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Float32Array']
values: Float32Array(138) [4.005720615386963, 94.61279296875, -11.993070602416992, 4.005720615386963, 94.6389389038086, -11.980019569396973, 4.005720615386963, 94.71439361572266, -11.942364692687988, 4.005720615386963, 94.83453369140625, -11.882410049438477, 4.005720615386963, 94.99461364746094, -11.802521705627441, 4.005720615386963, 95.18978881835938, -11.705118179321289, 4.005720615386963, 95.41510009765625, -11.592676162719727, 4.005720615386963, 95.66551208496094, -11.467708587646484, 4.005720615386963, 95.9359359741211, -11.33275318145752, 4.005720615386963, 96.22123718261719, -11.190374374389648, 4.005720615386963, 96.5162582397461, -11.043142318725586, 4.005720615386963, 96.81581115722656, -10.893649101257324, 4.005720615386963, 97.11476135253906, -10.744461059570312, 4.005720615386963, 97.40798950195312, -10.598123550415039, 4.005720615386963, 97.69041442871094, -10.45718002319336, 4.005720615386963, 97.95703887939453, -10.32412052154541, 4.005720615386963, 98.20294952392578, -10.201398849487305, 4.005720615386963, 98.42332458496094, -10.091418266296387, 4.005720615386963, 98.61348724365234, -9.9965181350708, 4.005720615386963, 98.76885986328125, -9.91898250579834, 4.005720615386963, 98.88501739501953, -9.861011505126953, 4.005720615386963, 98.95771026611328, -9.824735641479492, 4.005720615386963, 98.98281860351562, -9.812203407287598, 4.005720615386963, 98.95790100097656, -9.824639320373535, 4.005720615386963, 98.88645935058594, -9.86029052734375, 4.005720615386963, 98.77338409423828, -9.91672134399414, 4.005720615386963, 98.6234359741211, -9.991554260253906, 4.005720615386963, 98.44127655029297, -10.0824613571167, 4.005720615386963, 98.23147583007812, -10.187163352966309, 4.005720615386963, 97.99851989746094, -10.30341911315918, 4.005720615386963, 97.74683380126953, -10.429024696350098, 4.005720615386963, 97.48075866699219, -10.561807632446289, 4.005720615386963, 97.20460510253906, -10.699623107910156, 4.005720615386963, …]
[[Prototype]]: KeyframeTrack
1: QuaternionKeyframeTrack
createInterpolant: ƒ InterpolantFactoryMethodLinear( result )
name: "BD_Spine_01_jnt.quaternion"
times: Float32Array(46) [0, 0.01666666753590107, 0.03333333507180214, 0.05000000074505806, 0.06666667014360428, 0.0833333358168602, 0.10000000149011612, 0.11666666716337204, 0.13333334028720856, 0.15000000596046448, 0.1666666716337204, 0.18333333730697632, 0.20000000298023224, 0.21666666865348816, 0.23333333432674408, 0.25, 0.2666666805744171, 0.28333333134651184, 0.30000001192092896, 0.3166666626930237, 0.3333333432674408, 0.3499999940395355, 0.36666667461395264, 0.38333332538604736, 0.4000000059604645, 0.4166666567325592, 0.4333333373069763, 0.44999998807907104, 0.46666666865348816, 0.4833333194255829, 0.5, 0.5166666507720947, 0.5333333611488342, 0.550000011920929, 0.5666666626930237, 0.5833333134651184, 0.6000000238418579, 0.6166666746139526, 0.6333333253860474, 0.6499999761581421, 0.6666666865348816, 0.6833333373069763, 0.699999988079071, 0.7166666388511658, 0.7333333492279053, 0.75, buffer: ArrayBuffer(184), byteLength: 184, byteOffset: 0, length: 46, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Float32Array']
values: Float32Array(184) [0.6915496587753296, 0.27959248423576355, -0.35657379031181335, 0.5625320076942444, 0.6915093660354614, 0.2795647978782654, -0.3565693795681, 0.5625981092453003, 0.6913931965827942, 0.2794851064682007, -0.35655641555786133, 0.5627886652946472, 0.6912081837654114, 0.27935895323753357, -0.35653501749038696, 0.563092052936554, 0.6909617185592651, 0.2791922390460968, -0.35650500655174255, 0.5634960532188416, 0.6906613111495972, 0.27899107336997986, -0.356466144323349, 0.5639883279800415, 0.6903147101402283, 0.27876177430152893, -0.3564181923866272, 0.5645560622215271, 0.6899297833442688, 0.27851054072380066, -0.3563610017299652, 0.5651863813400269, 0.6895143389701843, 0.2782435119152069, -0.3562946617603302, 0.5658662915229797, 0.6890764236450195, 0.27796661853790283, -0.35621950030326843, 0.5665826797485352, 0.6886240243911743, 0.2776854932308197, -0.3561362326145172, 0.5673224329948425, 0.6881651878356934, 0.27740541100502014, -0.3560458719730377, 0.5680724382400513, 0.687707781791687, 0.2771313190460205, -0.35594993829727173, 0.5688197016716003, 0.6872597336769104, 0.27686768770217896, -0.3558502197265625, 0.5695515275001526, 0.6868287920951843, 0.2766186594963074, -0.3557489514350891, 0.5702552199363708, 0.6864225268363953, 0.27638792991638184, -0.35564863681793213, 0.5709184408187866, 0.6860482692718506, 0.2761789560317993, -0.3555521070957184, 0.5715292096138, 0.6857133507728577, 0.2759947180747986, -0.35546228289604187, 0.5720757842063904, 0.6854246854782104, 0.27583804726600647, -0.3553822636604309, 0.5725468397140503, 0.6851890683174133, 0.27571165561676025, -0.3553152084350586, 0.572931170463562, 0.6850130558013916, 0.2756180763244629, -0.3552640378475189, 0.5732183456420898, 0.6849029660224915, 0.2755599319934845, -0.3552316129207611, 0.5733978748321533, 0.6848649382591248, 0.27553993463516235, -0.35522031784057617, 0.5734599232673645, 0.6849026679992676, 0.27555978298187256, -0.35523152351379395, 0.5733983516693115, 0.6850108504295349, 0.27561691403388977, -0.3552634119987488, 0.5732218623161316, …]
[[Prototype]]: KeyframeTrack
2: QuaternionKeyframeTrack {name: 'R_BD_NB_Hip_jnt.quaternion', times: Float32Array(46), values: Float32Array(184), createInterpolant: ƒ}
3: QuaternionKeyframeTrack {name: 'R_BD_NB_Knee_jnt.quaternion', times: Float32Array(46), values: Float32Array(184), createInterpolant: ƒ}
4: QuaternionKeyframeTrack {name: 'R_BD_NB_Ankle_jnt.quaternion', times: Float32Array(46), values: Float32Array(184), createInterpolant: ƒ}
5: QuaternionKeyframeTrack {name: 'R_BD_NB_Ball_jnt.quaternion', times: Float32Array(46), values: Float32Array(184), createInterpolant: ƒ}
...
```

Comment: I posted an answer. That should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rotate the object during the time the clip is being run. Let's say you want to flip the `100th` clip.

```js
if(clip == 100) {
    model.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2 //Depending on the axis you want to rotate along
}
```

This will also work for `nth` clip, depending on what you need. To flip the whole thing, just rotate the model before initializing the `AnimationMixer`.

```js
model.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
```

**Update**

The more efficient way would be to edit the model in an animation software, such as [Blender](https://blender.org), and manually adjust the mirroring there. Three.js runs on WebGL, which is really powerful, but three.js isn't designed to create/update animation. Three.js is more designed to run an existing animation.

Comment: With a rotation I think it will happen the same that with a scale: I wouldn't be able to use "crossFadeFrom" to get a smooth transition between animations:

https://youtu.be/6BPp6I9QZfA

Comment: I updated my original answer to address your issue.

Comment: _> but three.js isn't designed to create/update animation_

Well, I successfully manipulated some values to accomplish some objectives. For example, I could set to 0 x and z coordinates of the main track of an animation (the root) so that it didn't move from the place it was. It's just quaternions what I don't understand enough to be able to manipulate them at will, but I'm sure it could be really easy with the proper documentation.

Blender didn't help me so far but probably I will give it a 2nd try :)

Comment: Blender is just an example. Use whatever you are comfortable with! If this worked, it would be great if you could accept the answer!

Comment: I am learning Blender as well as Three.js with this, It's my first approach to this 3D world :)

Comment: Okay! It would be great if you would accept this answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't think someone who is searching for this same problem is happy with an obvious workaround that is not even solved, since it's not as simple as it seems. I opened a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71315607/is-there-a-way-to-flip-an-animation-horizontally) for that