# How can I flip an animation horizontally in Blender?

Tags: blender

I have an animation (an independent armature) that uses the right hand to bound a ball and I want it to use the left hand instead, so I need to mirror it like Unity does:

[Mirror in Unity](https://youtu.be/KHCNxUR9EmY)

I've tried to use the "mirror->X global" option over the animation and then "Names->flip names" so that the left bones are in the left side and the right bones in the right side. The armature seems to animate well in Blender but, when I use it on a model in Three.js, it looks like the angles are wrong, since the textures seem to be inside out:

[Mirror on Three.js](https://youtu.be/ei5IoYZXIag)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It didn't work yet, but I don't know if it's cause of my model or if it's another thing. I want to try it from scratch but I'm also looking for other solutions ... Anyways, I don't forget this :)

Comment: Did you get my answer? It would be great if you could accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jt1ifwe5PYs) tutorial. It shows you how you can flip/mirror any animation in Blender. Unity, three.js, and Blender are all really similar, because they all have the same purpose - 3D Manipulation. If one of these tools can do it, it is likely that the others can too. In this case, Unity can do it, so Blender can as well.

Comment: That solution seems to work only partially. The problem I see is that the animation seems to be flipped in a relative way instead of in an absolute way. The initial position of the model seems to remain the same, making that only the hand movement changes. However, the arms should be changed too and they aren't

https://vimeo.com/703746453